# What is the difference between "man" and "info" documentation?

Tags: documentation, info, manpage

Regarding man-pages and info help documentation:

Why do two such similar sources of documentation exist?
Sometimes a man-page is available and the info is not; or vice-versa.
I haven't yet latched on to the rhyme and reason behind it.

Maybe there is a significant difference between them, but even if there is, why do they both exist?  It seems like unnecessary doubling up.

Comment: [GNU-Info Bad, Man(1) Good](http://www.advogato.org/article/732.html) from 2003 funny read. `Flat is better than nested.`

Comment: Try doing `info info` and `man info`. `man info` shows colorful examples. I am more visual person, using the same color across makes me sleepy. The man syntax with a little color makes it understandable quickly.

Comment: @randominstanceOfLivingThing - on my machine, 20.04.1 i don't see any colors with `info xyz`  or `info info` . Any thing to tweak

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Man pages are the UNIX traditional way of distributing documentation about programs.  The term "man page" itself is short for "manual page", as they correspond to the pages of the printed manual; the man pages "sections" (1 for commands, 2 for system calls, etc.) correspond to sections in the full UNIX manual.  Support is still there if you want to print a man page to paper, although this is rarely done these days, and the sheer number of man pages make it just impossible to bind them all into a single book.

In the early '90s, the [GNU project](http://www.gnu.org) decided that "man" documentation system was outdated, and wrote the [info](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/1/info) command to replace it: *info* has basic hyperlinking features and a simpler markup language to use (compared to the "troff" system used for man pages).  In addition, GNU [advocates against the use of man pages at all](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Man-Pages) and contends that complex software systems should have complete and comprehensive documentation rather than just a set of short man pages.

There are actually other documentation systems in use, besides *man* and *info*: GNOME and KDE have their own, HTML-based system, etc.

In the end, the form in which you get documentation depends on the internal policies of the project that provided the software in the first place -- there is no globally accepted standard.

Comment: `info` never really took off, did it?

Comment: @UncleZeiv: run `info` without parameters to get an idea about how many applications use info-format documentation.

Answer (score 35):

Info is the default format for documentation inside the GNU project, man is the much older traditional format for UNIX.

Info uses Texinfo as its source format, which is a bunch of macros for TeX, and that makes it much easier to also create "good-looking" printed versions or PDFs.

Generally, manpages are more about 1 specific topic (a command, a config file, a system function, ...) while info normally has more the structure of a combined manual, more like a book.

Answer (score 19):

man uses less to display the manual page which in turn uses vim keybindings while info uses emacs keybindings and standard emacs commands for search, quitting etc.

Comment: The keybindings issue is interesting (so I googled)... It seems that `info` has a VI keybindings option: --vi-keys (Use *vi-like* and *less-like* key bindings) ...  $ alias info='info --vi-keys' ... maybe?