# Understanding complex psql command

Tags: 14.04

I was just going through an online tutorial on psql and came across the following command:

```
psql -U user -d postgres -f ~/Desktop/pgrouting-workshop/data/sampledata_notopo.sql
```

I am just wondering what all those parameters `-d` and `-f`, I am new to Ubuntu and don't even know what keyword to search for, So that i could get the documentation for those flags.

Can somebody break it down for me?

Comment: Where did you install psql from as it does not appear to have a `man` page?

Answer (score 1):

As another user pointed out, in Ubuntu (and other Linux distributions), you can typically find man (manual) pages with the man command, e.g.:

```
    man psql
```

which would give you a "man page" on how to use the "psql" command. Alternatively, you can also try the info command, e.g.:

```
    info man
```

which would give you information on the "man" command.

For a brief overview of man vs. info, look [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9325/what-is-the-difference-between-man-and-info-documentation).

The psql command as you are using it can be broken down:

```
    psql
```

(the command itself)

```
    -U user
```

(connect as the user named "user")

```
    -d postgres
```

(to the database named postgres)

```
    -f ...
```

(use the filename located at ... as the source for the queries, as opposed to interactively ).

In brief, Linux commands generally take the form:

```
    command -option(s) arguments .
```

Comment: one question ! , i am still not getting the use of the `-f` flag ! why is it being used ?

Comment: Per the man page for the psql command: "Use the file filename as the source of commands instead of reading commands interactively". In your circumstance, you are specifying the: `-f sampledata_notopo.sql` file.